# Double index numbers in array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

The array counts is as follows:

```
counts = ["a", 1]
```

What does this:

```
counts[0][0]
```

refer to?

I've only seen this before:

```
array[idx]
```

but never this:

```
array[idx][idx]
```

where idx is an integer.

*This is the entire code where the snippet of code before was from:*

```
  def num_repeats(string) #abab
    counts = [] #array

    str_idx = 0 
    while str_idx < string.length #1 < 4
      letter = string[str_idx] #b

      counts_idx = 0 
      while counts_idx < counts.length #0 < 1
        if counts[counts_idx][0] == letter #if counts[0][0] == b
          counts[counts_idx][1] += 1
          break
        end
        counts_idx += 1
      end

      if counts_idx == counts.length #0 = 0
        # didn't find this letter in the counts array; count it for the
        # first time
        counts.push([letter, 1]) #counts = ["a", 1]
      end

      str_idx += 1
    end

    num_repeats = 0
    counts_idx = 0
    while counts_idx < counts.length
      if counts[counts_idx][1] > 1
        num_repeats += 1
      end

      counts_idx += 1
    end

    return counts
  end
```

Comment: Hint: do you know what `foo[bar]` does? Do you know what `foo.bar.baz` does? Then, what does `foo[bar][baz]` do?

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
arr[0]
```

Gets the first item of the array `arr`, in some cases this may also be an array (Or another indexable object) this means you can get that object and get an object from that array:

```
# if arr = [["item", "another"], "last"]
item = arr[0]
inner_item = item[0]
puts inner_item # => "item"
```

This can be shortened to

```
arr[0][0]
```

So any 2 dimensional array or array containing indexable objects can work like this, e.g. with an array of strings:

```
arr = ["String 1", "Geoff", "things"]
arr[0] # => "String 1"
arr[0][0] # => "S"
arr[1][0] # => "G"
```

Comment: Give an example with strings (a longer string, perhaps), because that's what the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

It's for nested indexing

```
a = [ "item 0", [1, 2, 3] ]
a[0] #=> "item 0"
a[1] #=> [1, 2, 3]
a[1][0] #=> 1
```

Since the value at index 1 is another array you can use index referencing on that value as well.

**EDIT**

Sorry I didn't thoroughly read the original question. The array in question is

```
counts = ["a", 1]
```

In this case `counts[0]` returns `"a"` and since we can use indexes to references characters of a string, the 0th index in the string `"a"` is simply `"a"`.

```
str = "hello"
str[2] #=> "l"
str[1] #=> "e"
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're correct, I misread the original question and thought he was dealing with a nested array. Either way, I've corrected my answer.